# low fps when moving camera or objects and slow loading times

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

i have an RTX 3070 but even though, i put more than 3 objects blender starts lowering in fps and when switching between viewports it freezes for more than 30 seconds,i tried changing max fps in nvidia control panel and it didn't change anything.

Comment: The viewport is not really a realtime rendering engine and your GPU won't help much about it, because animations / movements are calculated with the CPU. I cannot stress it often enough on this site that the _Frame Rate_ settings you choose in the _Output Properties_ (output!) are mostly necessary for creating video files to set the fps, and also for playback of rendered videos and image sequences. Another important use for the frame rate is calculating simulations. To know how quick simulations are happening Blender needs to know in which speed you intend to play them afterwards.

Comment: Of course, the better the hardware and the simpler the scene, the higher the probability that you can watch animations almost in the correct speed. But nevertheless, if you for example want to check if movements look correct or fluent, many tutorials on Youtube highly recommend that you render the animations to really judge the movements. And to not have to wait for ages for a rendered animation, it's best to use _View_ > _Viewport Render Animation_ from the menu.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.